# How to reduce dpi to 72 for thumbs in paperclip, originals are 300 - rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip, dpi

Other posts claim that paperclip reduces dpi to 72 when processing, but this is not true. Out of the box, it leaves dpi untouched. 
I need 300dpi originals in print quality, but the thumbs should be 72dpi for monitor. How can I do this (whilst processing the upload)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
has_attached_file :uploadedPhoto, 
                  :styles          => {:portrait => "400x", :icon => "32x32#"},
                  :convert_options => {:portrait => '-strip -quality 60', :icon => '-strip -quality 60' }
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain why/how this works.

Comment: Probably the worst explanation I've ever read on SO. It's the same as "because it works"